# Can't create DebugCoverageReport in Android Studio (Linux)

Tags: java, android, linux, gradle

When I try to execute

> ./gradle createDebugCoverageReport

command in terminal it says

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

And of course it's not creating this report . Any solutions ?